# One of the table in AWS Aurora is unresponsive on update queries - Need Help Identifying the Issue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora

I am facing a perplexing issue with an AWS Aurora(Postgres) database instance that includes one replica. Recently, one of the tables in this setup started behaving abnormally, and I'm looking for assistance in identifying the root cause and possible solutions.

Problem Description:
The table in question seems to be unresponsive when attempting to update rows even though there are less than 10 rows in it. The strange part is that the behavior is inconsistent - sometimes the update query takes an unusually long time, up to 10 minutes, to complete, while other times it seems to run indefinitely without any results. A simple reboot did fix the issue but after a few row updates same issue persists. I have tried performing the updates through my TypeORM(nodejs)-based application and directly using DBeaver, ruling out any potential issues related to the ORM.

Other tables in the database do not exhibit this issue as far as I know; it is isolated to this particular table.

Additional Information:

The only thing I can find from AWS logs is:

```
2023-07-20 09:14:02 UTC:0.0.0.0(44432):xyz@xyz:[3111]:WARNING: unrecognized node type: 378
2023-07-20 09:28:50 UTC:0.0.0.0(38600):xyz@xyz:[3117]:LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
```

Database: AWS Aurora serverless v2 with one replica instance

Application: TypeORM-based Node.js application

Cluster storage configuration: Aurora I/O-Optimized

Database Engine: [PostgreSQL 14.7]

I'm at a loss regarding the possible cause of this erratic behavior. If anyone has encountered similar issues with AWS Aurora or any other database systems, or if you have any suggestions on further investigating and resolving this problem, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Thanks

Comment: This is nothing more than a shot in the dark, but on Aurora Serverless PostgreSQL (original PG10--not the newer versions under V2), we had a problem with tables that had multiple large columns.  In our case, the tables were created through an ETL tool  that included all columns and contained MIME64 representations of images in `text` columns.  We had intermittent problems with major slowdowns on `select` and the `update` steps in the ETL job.  Since we did not need those columns for our purposes, we removed them from the tables and the ETL jobs, and the problem went away.

Comment: in my case, the table has a limited number of columns, and there are fewer than 10 rows available. Don't know how it's possible for the table to have such a slow query execution.

Comment: An *inconsistent* problem may very well not be related directly to the observation, but to another process taking a lock and not releasing in a timely matter. It may be worth looking into this. See [Viewing Locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-locks.html).

Comment: can locks be the issue if the rows in this table are only ever updated without any transaction/locks and created through a  DB GUI in this case DBeaver?